# .Net Core Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets missing after installing VS 2015 Update 3

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I'm using VS 2015 Community Edition
I've installed VS 2015 update 3.
And also I've already **checked Web Developer Tools** during instalation ( following question's problem was not selecting it [Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets missing after installing .NET Core RTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124900/microsoft-dotnet-web-targets-missing-after-installing-net-core-rtm#))

And here I'm opening a project(which developed using VS2015 Community Edition, from VSTS. And when I open the solution it gives following errors.

Error 1

[image]

Error 2

[image]

Error 3

[image]

And the **Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets** file is not available in the required directory even I installed Web Developer tools.

I've installed following along with the Update 3

[image]

I've repaired the visual studio and update 3 again

Comment: Did you also repair the `VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2`? (or run the exe of that again)

Comment: @MartinUllrich.. No I didn't , I'll do it now and check

Comment: @MartinUllrich.. still the problem exists :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've searched a lot and found the issue.
The **issue was my Powershell Version was 2.0** 
And when I updated it to the latest Version (4.0). It worked.

> ASP.NET 5: On Windows 7 SP1, DNX SDK cannot be installed without
>   Powershell 3.0.

Following Answer Will help.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31549273/3156647