# VS2017 Searching for wrong folders for libraries

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

While running a dotnet core 1.1.8 project, my build is failing because it is searching for Microsoft.Application.targets in 
`C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\sdk\1.1.8\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`

but the actual file exists at

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`

Normally it should be looking into the 2nd path, but I am confused why it is looking in wrong path.

Please help.

Comment: Does it build from the command line? Do you have any environment variables which refer to part of the first path?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124900/microsoft-dotnet-web-targets-missing-after-installing-net-core-rtm could this be helpful..??

Comment: Does it build from the command line? Yes we use dotnet restore (This is where actual error occurs)
Do you have any environment variables which refer to part of the first path? In my knowledge No